# How to dynamically catch a parent of ID in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td><input type="submit" id="view_{{ var }}" value="View"></td><td>
```

I need to catch this `id` pattern. I have multiple submit button in the table. Whose `id` are variable but having a common pattern. On clicking each submit button the first and second `<td>` value of same row should be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Attribute Starts With](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

`$('input[id^="view_"]')`

Comment: ^= is the starts with selector

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = $('input[id^="view_"]');
var id = a.attr("id").replace("view_", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd place a `.delegate()` handler on the `<table>`, with a selector to match the submit inputs.

```
$('#myTable').delegate(':submit', 'click', function() {
    var id_value = this.id.split('_')[1];
    alert( id_value );
    // and so on
});
```

If there are other `<input type='submit' />` elements in the table, then you could use a more specific selector to target only those.